# if the input is disabled as i move to the next item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i move from element #2 to #4 if element #3 is disabled using the next function

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focusable: function (el, index, selector) {
        return $(el).is('[tabindexgt],[tabindexdxfiltro]');
    } 
});

$(document).on('keypress','input,select', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get all focusable elements on the page
        var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
        var index = $canfocus.index(document.activeElement) + 1;
        if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
        $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector try changing:

```
var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
```

To

```
var $canfocus = $(':focusable').not(':disabled');
```